# Why is the variable inside the compiled code a tensor but not a scalar?

Tags: syntax, compile

Consider the data `data0`, `data1`:

```
data0 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10^4, 3}];
(*Number of columns pairs*)
npairs = 12;
data1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 2*npairs}];
```

and some function `func1` that would use the values of `data0`, `data1`:

```
func1[x1_, y1_, x2_, y2_, X0_, Y0_] = 
 Exp[-x1^2 - y1^2 - x2^2 - y2^2]/(X0^2 + Y0^2);
```

I would like to sum some boolean conditions using `func1` for the following combinations of pairs of columns of `data1`:

```
PairCombinations={{1,2},{1,8},{2,12},{3,9},{4,5},{4,8}};
```

This is my code:

```
compblock2 = 
 Hold@Compile[{{data0, _Real, 1}, {data1, _Real, 
       2}, {PairCombinations, _Real, 2}}, 
     Module[{count, X0val, Y0val, xval1, yval1, xval2, yval2, Func1, 
       comb1, comb2}, count = 0.;
      X0val = Compile`GetElement[data0, 1];
      Y0val = Compile`GetElement[data0, 2];
      (*This Do goes over all pair combinations in the table PairCombination*)
      Do[
       (*These are the identifiers of the pairs of columns used in the calculation*)
       comb1 = PairCombinations[[m]][[1]];
       comb2 = PairCombinations[[m]][[2]];
       (*This Do goes over all rows of data1*)
       Do[
        (*Here I extract the values of the selected columns*)
        xval1 = Compile`GetElement[data1, i, 2*(comb1 - 1) + 1];
        yval1 = Compile`GetElement[data1, i, 2*(comb1 - 1) + 2];
        xval2 = Compile`GetElement[data1, i, 2*(comb2 - 1) + 1];
        yval2 = Compile`GetElement[data1, i, 2*(comb2 - 1) + 2];
        Func1 = func1[xval1, yval1, xval2, yval2, X0val, Y0val];
        (*This is the summation of boolean conditions*)
        count += Boole[Func1 > 0.001], {i, 1, Length[data1], 1}], {m, 
        1, Length[PairCombinations], 1}];
      {count}], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True] /. 
   DownValues@func1 // ReleaseHold
```

When trying to compile the code, I get the error:

> Compile::argcompten: The comparison, Greater, is invalid for tensor
> arguments.

This means that `Func1` (and already `xval1`, etc.) is not the quantity of the desired type (scalar), but a tensor instead. I do not understand what is the origin of this problem.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As often with `Comiple`, `` CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint `` is your friend: Since the function won't compile at all in its current state, I removed the problematic expression by trying `count += Func1`, and then I replaced `count=0.` with `count={{0.}}` to get rid of the error about tensor ranks in the addition. At this point, you can look at the compiled version of the function:

```
compblock2 = 
 Hold@Compile[{{data0, _Real, 1}, {data1, _Real, 
       2}, {PairCombinations, _Integer, 2}}, 
     Module[{count, X0val, Y0val, xval1, yval1, xval2, yval2, Func1, 
       comb1, comb2}, count = {{0.}};
      X0val = Compile`GetElement[data0, 1];
      Y0val = Compile`GetElement[data0, 2];
      (*This Do goes over all pair combinations in the table \
PairCombination*)
      Do[(*These are the identifiers of the pairs of columns used in \
the calculation*)comb1 = PairCombinations[[m]][[1]];
       comb2 = PairCombinations[[m]][[2]];
       (*This Do goes over all rows of data1*)
       Do[(*Here I extract the values of the selected columns*)
        xval1 = Compile`GetElement[data1, i, 2*(comb1 - 1) + 1];
        yval1 = Compile`GetElement[data1, i, 2*(comb1 - 1) + 2];
        xval2 = Compile`GetElement[data1, i, 2*(comb2 - 1) + 1];
        yval2 = Compile`GetElement[data1, i, 2*(comb2 - 1) + 2];
        Func1 = func1[xval1, yval1, xval2, yval2, X0val, Y0val];
        (*This is the summation of boolean conditions*)
        count += Func1, {i, 1, Length[data1], 1}], {m, 1, 
        Length[PairCombinations], 1}];
      {count}], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True] /. 
   DownValues@func1 // ReleaseHold

<< CompiledFunctionTools`

CompilePrint@compblock2
(* "    3 arguments
        10 Integer registers
        7 Real registers
        15 Tensor registers
        Underflow checking off
        Overflow checking off
        Integer overflow checking off
        RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}

        T(R1)0 = A1
        T(R2)1 = A2
        T(R2)2 = A3
        I4 = 0
        I1 = 2
        I9 = -1
        I0 = 1
        T(R2)3 = {{0.}}
        Result = T(R3)8

1   T(R2)9 = CopyTensor[ T(R2)3]]
2   R3 = GetElement[ T(R1)0, I0]
3   R2 = GetElement[ T(R1)0, I1]
4   I3 = Length[ T(R2)2]
5   I5 = I4
6   goto 84
7   T(R1)7 = Part[ T(R2)2, I5]
8   R1 = Part[ T(R1)7, I0]
9   T(R1)7 = Part[ T(R2)2, I5]
10  R0 = Part[ T(R1)7, I1]
11  I7 = Length[ T(R2)1]
12  I8 = I4
13  goto 83
14  R5 = I9
15  R4 = R1 + R5
16  R5 = I1
17  R5 = R5 * R4
18  R4 = I0
19  R5 = R5 + R4
20  R4 = I9
21  R6 = R1 + R4
22  R4 = I1
23  R4 = R4 * R6
24  R6 = I0
25  R4 = R4 + R6
26  T(R2)7 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[Compile`GetElement][ T(R2)1, I8, R4]]
27  R5 = I9
28  R4 = R1 + R5
29  R5 = I1
30  R5 = R5 * R4
31  R4 = I1
32  R5 = R5 + R4
33  R4 = I9
34  R6 = R1 + R4
35  R4 = I1
36  R4 = R4 * R6
37  R6 = I1
38  R4 = R4 + R6
39  T(R2)6 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[Compile`GetElement][ T(R2)1, I8, R4]]
40  R5 = I9
41  R4 = R0 + R5
42  R5 = I1
43  R5 = R5 * R4
44  R4 = I0
45  R5 = R5 + R4
46  R4 = I9
47  R6 = R0 + R4
48  R4 = I1
49  R4 = R4 * R6
50  R6 = I0
51  R4 = R4 + R6
52  T(R2)5 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[Compile`GetElement][ T(R2)1, I8, R4]]
53  R5 = I9
54  R4 = R0 + R5
55  R5 = I1
56  R5 = R5 * R4
57  R4 = I1
58  R5 = R5 + R4
59  R4 = I9
60  R6 = R0 + R4
61  R4 = I1
62  R4 = R4 * R6
63  R6 = I1
64  R4 = R4 + R6
65  T(R2)4 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[Compile`GetElement][ T(R2)1, I8, R4]]
66  T(R2)11 = Square[ T(R2)7]
67  T(R2)12 = - T(R2)11
68  T(R2)11 = Square[ T(R2)5]
69  T(R2)8 = - T(R2)11
70  T(R2)11 = Square[ T(R2)6]
71  T(R2)13 = - T(R2)11
72  T(R2)11 = Square[ T(R2)4]
73  T(R2)14 = - T(R2)11
74  T(R2)12 = T(R2)12 + T(R2)8 + T(R2)13 + T(R2)14
75  T(R2)8 = Exp[ T(R2)12]
76  R5 = Square[ R3]
77  R4 = Square[ R2]
78  R5 = R5 + R4
79  R4 = Reciprocal[ R5]
80  T(R2)12 = R4 * T(R2)8
81  T(R2)8 = T(R2)9 + T(R2)12
82  T(R2)9 = CopyTensor[ T(R2)8]]
83  if[ ++ I8 <= I7] goto 14
84  if[ ++ I5 <= I3] goto 7
85  T(R3)8 = {T(R2)9}
86  Return " *)
```

Immediately problematic is any line with `MainEvaluate`, because that is usually an indication that `Compile` didn't understand something as expected. Let's look at the first of them:

```
26  T(R2)7 = MainEvaluate[ Hold[Compile`GetElement][ T(R2)1, I8, R4]]
```

The `T(Rx)y` is to be read as "tensor of rank `x`, number `y`. Similarly, `Ix` is the `x`th integer register, and `Ry` the `y`th real register. So what is happening is that compile thinks you are doing something of the form

```
Compile`GetElement[{{...},...}, 123, 2.4]
```

which is obviously wrong. Tracking down where `R4` comes from, you'll see that it ultimately comes from

```
7   T(R1)7 = Part[ T(R2)2, I5]
8   R1 = Part[ T(R1)7, I0]
```

which in turn come from

```
T(R2)2 = A3
```

This means that because `A3` (the third argument) is declared as a rank 2 tensor of reals, `Compile` decided that your `` Compile`GetElement `` call gets a real number as index, making it invalid. Knowing this, the fix is easy: Simply replace `{PairCombinations, _Real, 2}` with `{PairCombinations, _Integer, 2}`:

```
compblock2 = 
 Hold@Compile[{{data0, _Real, 1}, {data1, _Real, 
       2}, {PairCombinations, _Integer, 2}}, 
     Module[{count, X0val, Y0val, xval1, yval1, xval2, yval2, Func1, 
       comb1, comb2}, count = 0.;
      X0val = Compile`GetElement[data0, 1];
      Y0val = Compile`GetElement[data0, 2];
      (*This Do goes over all pair combinations in the table \
PairCombination*)
      Do[(*These are the identifiers of the pairs of columns used in \
the calculation*)comb1 = PairCombinations[[m]][[1]];
       comb2 = PairCombinations[[m]][[2]];
       (*This Do goes over all rows of data1*)
       Do[(*Here I extract the values of the selected columns*)
        xval1 = Compile`GetElement[data1, i, 2*(comb1 - 1) + 1];
        yval1 = Compile`GetElement[data1, i, 2*(comb1 - 1) + 2];
        xval2 = Compile`GetElement[data1, i, 2*(comb2 - 1) + 1];
        yval2 = Compile`GetElement[data1, i, 2*(comb2 - 1) + 2];
        Func1 = func1[xval1, yval1, xval2, yval2, X0val, Y0val];
        (*This is the summation of boolean conditions*)
        count += Boole[Func1 > 0.001], {i, 1, Length[data1], 1}], {m, 
        1, Length[PairCombinations], 1}];
      {count}], CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", 
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True] /. 
   DownValues@func1 // ReleaseHold
```